# CRM 2015 - Show an alert based on records existing in another identity

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm working on a project where I've been asked to show an alert in the "Account" form that notifies our users that an active record exists in a custom entity.

From the reading I have done so far I can see that
Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification('Message here', 'WARNING') appears to have the exact functionality that I need, but, how do I go about implementing the logic that shows this message. Presumably I need to do a count of associated records in this entity and if it's > 0 then show the alert, but, do I need to do this via a plug-in or is it Jquery? Or, am I vastly overcomplicating the issue when there is OOB functionality that will do this?

Any advice appreciated!
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your custom entity is a sub grid on the account form you can do this using JavaScript.

```
var count = Xrm.Page.getControl("custom_grid").getGrid().getTotalRecordCount();

if(count > 0) {
     Xrm.Page.ui.setFormNotification('Message here', 'WARNING')
}
```

If its not a sub grid you will need to perform an API call to count the number of related records, you are best using the Web API, [Use Microsoft Dynamics CRM web services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608128.aspx).

Comment: Much appreciated - This has set me along the path for completing what I need to do. 

It's not a sub grid (as the account page is already rather cluttered with sub grids). I'll go down the Web API route.

Answer (score 1):

The standard functionality you have at your disposal is roughly:

- Workflows
- Plugins
- Business Rules
- JavaScript

Of these options, only JavaScript currently supports setting form notifications. As a side-note, Business Rules do support showing error messages on specific fields (corresponding to [setNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#Anchor_12) from JavaScript).

You are thus correct that you would write JavaScript that determines whether the related records exist, and subsequently calls [setFormNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327828.aspx#Anchor_7).